# Is it legal to feed four subpanels in sequence from one breaker?

Tags: wiring, code-compliance, subpanel

I found one 100 amp 1ph breaker that feeds four subpanels down line. Is this legal? There is only one set of three #3 wires that is 200' to the first lugs that breakoff to the first panel, then 30' to the next set of lugs that feed 2 panels, then 50' to the last panel.

Comment: 240v 1Ø? How old? Separate buildings? Conduit? Jurisdiction?

Comment: Pictures of how the panels are connected would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

"the first lugs that breakoff to the first panel"? That's confusing. It also would be a lot easier to answer if we knew it this is one building or more.

If it's an over head feed to separate buildings and it's "split bolts" that break off at several poles then that's not necessarily a problem. The same could be accomplished with direct burial and rated splices in rated hand holes. Setups like this are common in small so-called "hobby farm" settings.

In a single building you could have a 100A feeder coming out of the service protected by a 100A breaker, then have the feeder daisy-chain through multiple 100A rated "main lug only" panels with lugs rated for multiple #3 conductors. Your typical hardware store panel would not meet this description. You could also have junction boxes ahead of each panel with splices rated for 3 conductors each, but those splices wouldn't typically be called "lugs".

Those are two completely different scenes that would be legal, but many details could violate the basic layouts, so more details are needed. Also you could run into "load calc" issues, and distance could be an issue in Canada.

3 wire? If this is in a single building you could have two hots, a neutral and metal conduit could serve as the ground, but a cable or feed in non-conductive raceway would require a 4th wire.

To out buildings some time in the 1990's the NEC changed configuration of feeders to a outbuilding now requiring 4 wires (two hots, a neutral, and ground) for a 240v 1Ø feeder with the neutral and ground separate at most locations after the service. Prior to that time feeders to buildings were configured like services with two hots and a grounded neutral, the bonding of ground electrodes to neutral at the first panel entering a building was done the same as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Each sub panel needs its own breaker. It sounds like the panels are double lugged, feed enters a lug and exits to the next panel from the same lug, and that's not allowed unless specified in the panel instructions. Even if the feed is properly WYE spliced into each sub panel (using Polaris connections) with no change in wire size, the one breaker setup is wrong.

Comment: There is no such requirement in the NEC, and you can get commercial panelboards with lugs specifically designed for this configuration

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I'm confused, so you're saying you can feed and exit a panel on the same standard lug?  I know you can get them that are approved for this but they're not standard. I doubt the installers got the approved lugs or commercial panels.

Comment: You can't stuff two wires into a lug, but you *can* splice/tap in the panel enclosure using Polaris connectors or a power distribution block.  (See also: riser panels)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Didn't I cover that in the last sentence of my answer?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I did edit to add the polaris connection for clarification.